# section_padding in CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm going through a youtube tuturial for react and I was wandering if and how this `CSS` command

```css
.gpt3__header {
    display: flex;
}
```

affects this `HTML` tag

```html
<div className="gpt3__header section_padding" id="home">
```

is `section_padding` some sought of internal CSS command? Which means `section_padding` is ignored in the class name `gpt3__header section_padding` consequently matching the `CSS` to the `HTML`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is. `gpt3__header` and `section_padding` are two different classes; the `.gpt__header` CSS selector means "*select all elements that has the class `gpt3__header`*", even if they have other classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML tags can have several classes, this can be done using the following syntax.

```html
class="className1 className2 className3..."
```

The CSS code you have included will affect any HTML element that has the class `.gpt3__header` regardless whether the element has another classes listed.

---

Further more, if you would like to apply some CSS code only to elements with both classes `gpt3__header` and `section_padding`, all you have to do is chain them like so:

```css
.gpt3__header.section_padding {
    display: flex;
}
```

The code above will **only** effect elements with both classes.

To further learn about CSS selectors and how they work check this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Here is a [website](https://kittygiraudel.github.io/selectors-explained/?s=.gpt3__header) that translates CSS selectors to plain English, this will help you avoid any confusion.